# Help with 1in Margins and Fancy Header (with a two-line header) on letter-paper

Tags: margins, fancyhdr, cv

I'm unable to get 1in margins on letter paper using geometry or manual layout with a two-line fancy header. Is there anything I can do besides make the header one line.

If possible, I'd like to use the geometry package to change the margins, however, they always print at larger than one inch using the geometry so I've resorted to manually manipulating them.

```
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND DOCUMENT PREAMBLE
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SET MARGINS MAUNALLY %\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} %showframe
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

%\usepackage{mathptmx}          % http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx (Similar to Times New Roman)
\usepackage{fontspec}           % Allows Custom Font (Needed for Times New Roman)
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}   % Set Times New Roman as Font
\usepackage{parskip}            % http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\newcommand{\showprivates}[1]{#1}                           % Shows Personal Information
%   \newcommand{\showprivates}[1]{Redacted for Web Publication} % Hides Personal Information

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}                                  % Clears the header and the footer
\fancyhead[R]{First M. Last \\ Page \thepage} % Top right header, name and page number
\fancyfoot[C]{\the\month-\the\day-\the\year} % Sets the footer in the center with the date
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes Fancyhdr header line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes Fancyhdr footer line

\title{First M Last CV}
\author{First Middle Last}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\setlength{\headheight}{28pt} % Fixes Fancyhdr Warning (Caused by the two line footer)
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING: NAME, ADDRESS, EMAIL, PHONE, DOCUMENT TITLE
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
 \begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty} % removes header and footer on first page
\begin{center}
\Large\textbf{First Middle Last}

\normalsize \showprivates{123 Main Street} \hfill \showprivates{(800) 567-0000}\\
\normalsize \showprivates{City, State 12345} \hfill 
\showprivates{firstmlast@gmail.com}\\

\begin{center}
\textit{Curriculum Vitae}
\end{center}

\end{center}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\section*\normalsize{\textbf{EDUCATION}}
\begin{flushleft}
X University, City, State\\
Ph.D. in X, Area of Specialization: X, Month 20XX\\
Dissertation: “Title: Subtitle”\\
GPA: 3.X

X University, City, State\\
MS in X, May 20XX\\
Thesis: “Title Goes Here”\\
GPA: 3.X

X University, City, State\\
B.S. in Neuroscience and Behavior, minor in Mathematics, May 20XX\\
Dual Honors, Thesis: “Title Goes Here”\\
GPA: 3.68
\end{flushleft}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ALL CONTENT SECTIONS
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage
\section*\normalsize{\textbf{{REFERENCES}}
\begin{flushleft}
Mike Pence, Ph.D.\\
Associate Professor\\
Dept. of X and X\\
X University\\
Building, Room XXX\\
City, State ZIP \\
\showprivates{703-219-8307}\\
\showprivates{firstlast@xxx.edu}\\
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushleft}
Jane Doe, Ph.D.\\
Associate Scientist\\ 
Department of X\\
X University\\
X Sciences, Room XXX\\
City, State ZIP\\
\showprivates{703-317-5289}\\
\showprivates{Jane Doe@xxx.edu}\\
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushleft}
Stacy Noll, Ph.D.\\
Assistant Program Director\\
Office of X and Y\\
Building, Room XXX\\
X University\\
City, State ZIP\\
\showprivates{703-219-3334}\\
\showprivates{StacyNoll@xxx.edu}\\
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushleft}
Michael Edward Moore, Ph.D.\\
Research Scientist\\
The Center for X and Z\\
X Sciences, Room XXX\\
X University\\
City, State ZIP\\
\showprivates{703-218-1299}\\
\showprivates{MichaelEdwardMoore@gmail.com}\\
\end{flushleft}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIN
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain your problem, do not **only** post some code! Do not missunderstand me, code is welcome here, but we need your explanaition what your problem is, could be it is not a problem for some of us?

Comment: for margins use only `geometry` and remove other manual page layout settings.

Answer (score 1):

as i noted in my comment above, the following settings work as expected:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SET MARGINS MAUNALLY %
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            margin=1in,
            headheight=28pt,
            showframe
            ]{geometry}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------

%\usepackage{mathptmx}          % http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx (Similar to Times New Roman)
\usepackage{fontspec}           % Allows Custom Font (Needed for Times New Roman)
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}   % Set Times New Roman as Font
\usepackage{parskip}            % http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\newcommand{\showprivates}[1]{#1}                           % Shows Personal Information
%   \newcommand{\showprivates}[1]{Redacted for Web Publication} % Hides Personal Information

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}                                  % Clears the header and the footer
\fancyhead[R]{First M. Last \\ Page \thepage} % Top right header, name and page number
\fancyfoot[C]{\the\month-\the\day-\the\year} % Sets the footer in the center with the date
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes Fancyhdr header line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes Fancyhdr footer line

\title{First M Last CV}
\author{First Middle Last}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING: NAME, ADDRESS, EMAIL, PHONE, DOCUMENT TITLE
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
 \begin{document}
...
```

you can see, that all manual page layout settings are removed and used only `geometry` package for determining your page layout.

**edit:**
in case that in printed document margins are increased, than this is caused by used settings for your printer in pdf viewer. for example in adobe reader select in "page sizing & handling" option "fit" (100% scaling).

Comment: I appreciate your help, however even when printing with the modifications you recommend the margins print larger than one inch across all sides.

Comment: margins are as defined. see settings for your printer in pdf viewer. in adobe reader select in "page sizing & handling" option "fit" (100% scaling).